# Assets no cache grails

Tags: grails

I would like to disable cache Javascript. I'm using grails 2.5 and my folders

```
assets/javacript
assets/javacript/main.js
assets/javacript/app.js
assets/javacript/controllers/test.js
```

But in the browser:

```
/app/assets/main-e671abc52d2afd0725a1aa70972887d0.js
/app/assets/app-gre53twc52deyy3t43regf23534ewtewr.js
/app/assets//controllers/test.js
```

I tried add this lines in my config.groovy:

```
grails.assets.includes = ["controllers/*.js", "*/controllers/*.js", "/assets//controllers/*.js", "/assets/controllers/*.js"]
```

But my test.js file has not random code. The issue is that the file is in "controllers" folder

Comment: grails uses the hash to uniquely identify the js, changing one char changes the hash, therefore rendering the cache issue moot...